# Selenium goog:chromeOptions hash

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lambda

I'm trying to run Selenium in AWS Lambda (Python) and recently learned that since Chromedriver version 2.31 they changed `chromeOptions` to `goog:chromeOptions`

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/notes.txt
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Chrome/Options.html

I am running Chromium 86 with Selenium 3.14. I've been troubleshooting multiple error messages for the past hours and I suspect this is my underlying issue I just dont know how can I pass this argument to the driver or selenium. I've been trying the following with no luck

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options='goog:chromeOptions')
```

or

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('goog:chromeOptions')
```

EDIT

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The change is made in Chromedriver... so when it sends the dictionary (transmitted as JSON) to the Chrome browser via wire protocol, it uses goog:chromeOptions.  So basically it's not relevant to any Selenium code you are writing.

Comment: Also see: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#protocol-extensions

Answer (score 1):

You saw it right.

You have to add the following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Now you can add any of the arguments. As an example:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
```

And finally:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

---

As an alternative,

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

---

### Update

[ChromeOptions object](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities#h.p_ID_106): Most Chrome-specific capabilities are exposed through the  `ChromeOptions` object. In some languages, this is implemented by the `ChromeOptions` class. In other languages, they are stored under the `goog:chromeOptions` dictionary in desired capabilities.

As an example, in [*Ruby*](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities#h.p_ID_52):

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(

     "goog:chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "window-size=1000,800" ]})

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Comment: Thanks. For my understanding based on your examples where does "goog:chromeOptions" key come into the picture? I dont see that being referenced anywhere. Also, what does "start-maximized" have to do with 'goog:chromeOptions'?

I also edited my OP with the current code I have. I might go with your alternative suggestion.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know if any questions.

Comment: @vboxer00 Any feedback?

Comment: Yes sorry for the late reply. My main problem still hasn't been fixed as I'm getting an error message 'Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally' which I thought has something to do with 'goog:chromeOptions'.

Are you saying for certain languages you have to use ChromeOptions and for some others goog:chromeOptions when passing additional args?